# Statements execution in Try block

Tags: java, try-catch

This is the Exception class:

```
public class IllegalValuesException extends Exception {
    public IllegalValuesException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    public IllegalValuesException() {
        super("Illegal Values");
    }
}
```

This is Tringle class:

```
public class Triangle {
    private double a, b, c;
    public Triangle(double x, double y, double z) throws IllegalValuesException {
        if(x+y > z && y+z > x && x+z > y) {
            a = x; b = y; c = z;
        }
        else
            throw new IllegalValuesException("Error: Values "+x+", "+y+", "+z+ " do not make a valid triangle");
    }

    public double area() {
        double s = this.perimeter()/2.0;
        return Math.sqrt(s*(s - a)*(s - b)*(s - c));
    }

    public double perimeter() {
        return a + b + c;
    }
}
```

This is my main Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle[] t = new Triangle[3];
        try {
            t[0] = new Triangle(6, 6, 6);
            t[1] = new Triangle(1, 4, 1);
            t[2] = new Triangle(4, 4, 4);
        }
        catch(IllegalValuesException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());

        }

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter an integer (from 1 to 3): ");
            int val = s.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Triangle: Area:" + t[val - 1].area() + " Perimeter: " +t[val -1].perimeter());
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e2) {
            System.out.println("You entered a non-integer!");
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e3) {
            System.out.println("You entered a value which is not in the range 1-3");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e4) {
            System.out.println("Sorry this triangle does not exist since it had illegal values");
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it, Tringle t[2] does not work and i get this:

```
Error: Values 1.0, 4.0, 1.0 do not make a valid triangle

Enter an integer (from 1 to 3): 
3

Sorry this triangle does not exist since it had illegal values
```

it never reaches `t[2]`, and it stops at `t[1]` because of the error.
I want to edit the Exception in the Tringle class :

```
public Triangle(double x, double y, double z) throws IllegalValuesException {
    if (x + y > z && y + z > x && x + z > y) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = z;
    } else
        throw new IllegalValuesException("Error: Values " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + " do not make a valid triangle");
}
```

In such a way that I can reach `t[2]`.

Comment: try splitting `t[0] = new Triangle(6, 6, 6);`  `t[1] = new Triangle(1, 4, 1);`  `t[2] = new Triangle(4, 4, 4);` into 3 parts, each with it's own try catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If exception occurs in try block’s body then control immediately transferred(skipping rest of the statements in try block) to the catch block. Once catch block finished execution then finally block and after that rest of the program. [source](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/flow-in-try-catch-finally/)**

Only `t[0] = new Triangle(6, 6, 6);` and `t[1] = new Triangle(1, 4, 1);` are executed and the second one throws an error so it's jumps to the `catch` part.

You are telling the compiler that you want to try to create 3 Triangles and might get an exception. So when it encounters the exception he moves to the catch part and checks if it's the exception you expected.

If you want to try and create each triangle you have to surround each statement with a try catch:

```
try {
    t[0] = new Triangle(6, 6, 6);
}
catch(IllegalValuesException e1) {
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());

} 

try {
    t[1] = new Triangle(1, 4, 1);
}
catch(IllegalValuesException e1) {
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());

}

try {
    t[2] = new Triangle(4, 4, 4);
}
catch(IllegalValuesException e1) {
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());

}
```

Comment: Thanks for "Alexandru Cimpanu".
Problem Solved

Comment: @YazeedAli glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what ***I want to edit the Exception in the Tringle class*** means but the problem is in the condition check `if (x + y > z && y + z > x && x + z > y)`. It returns `false` for `Triangle(1, 4, 1)` (1 + 1 isn't larger than 4) and there for the `else` is executed and you get `IllegalValuesException`.

If you don't want the exception to stop your program don't use an exception, just print it

```
if (x + y > z && y + z > x && x + z > y) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
    c = z;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Error: Values " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + " do not make a valid triangle");
}
```